# Exception using AssemblyInitialize - Invalid value for parameter. Value: -1

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Attempting to move a UI interaction into `[AssemblyInitialize]` so that it happens once before all of the tests are executed. It works as expected executed from a `[TestInitialize]` method. The exact same code throws this error when executed in `[AssemblyInitialize]`:

> Invalid value for parameter. Value: -1. Parameter:
>   SearchTimeout. Parameter name: SearchTimeout

Both methods are in the same base class for my tests.

```
[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext testContext)
{
    UIViews ui = new UIViews();
    Mouse.Click(ui.StationManager.Main.ResetInterlock); //Exception
}
```

Same code in my `TestInitialize` method:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void BaseTestInitialize()
{
    UIViews ui = new UIViews();
    Mouse.Click(ui.StationManager.Main.ResetInterlock); //Works as expected
}
```

I had a couple classes in my assembly marked as `[TestClass]` which I (throwing darts here) changed to `[CodedUITest]`. Same exception. I tried adding this to my `AssemblyInit` method:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 2000;
```

Same error. Not sure where to go from here except to just leave it in my `BaseTestInitialize` method.